# Model data not showing on template when iterating over queryset

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

So when building a simple Django website I found that for some reason I can't iterate over a queryset of a model I made and display the data in the template that I'm trying to create.

I have changed the keys of the dictionary being passed into the views and I have saved data on the model's database and changed around the template's format.

The database has values I checked using the Python Shell.

This is the template code:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3" >

    <h2 class="display-4"><center>Upcoming Events:</center></h2>


    { % for post in Posts % }
    <div class="row mt-3 ">

        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md">                    
            <h4> { { post.title } } </h4>

            <p class="lead">
                { { post.text } }
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="static_files/pictures/logo_main.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>

    </div>

    { % endfor % }
```

This is the views code that is interacting with the template:

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    Posts_ = Posts.objects.all()

    context = {

        'Posts':Posts_

    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

This is the model of interest:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    text            = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) 
    date_posted     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
author          = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put extra space between the curly braces, that is wrong syntax. You need to change:

- `{ { post.title } }` to `{{ post.title }}`
- `{ { post.text } }` to `{{ post.text }}`

Comment: I'm glad that worked. Can you please upvote my answer & flag that as correct?